# Cucumber Java. I’m having issues trying to build a boolean method

Tags: java, methods, automation, cucumber, boolean-expression

Cucumber Java. I’m having issues trying to build a boolean method that would do a assert where I want to validate: when I filter 50, the results would show 50. I’m trying to compare class="ng-scope active" selector with probably say linktext: 50

```
assert getElementTextBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ng-scope active']")).equals(By.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(),'50')]"));
```

Any ideas how I can get the right form?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hIRZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You compare text with WebElement.

Add get text for the second part also.

```
assert getElementTextBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ng-scope active']")).equals(getElementTextBy(By.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(),'50')]")));
```

If your input is 50 and you expect 50, you could only check that `getElementTextBy(secondeElement).equals("50")` , look for improvements.

Does not make much sense to say equal to a getText of an element that you identify based on the condition that has text 50.

filter by 50 => check there is a filter for 50, where 50 is the input from your test, so there is a known value.

If you need to check 2 elements then i would do 2 asserts and for each element i would check the text

Comment: Thanks! thats what I was missing!